# Concept behind the limit to infinity?

Tags: limits, infinity, nonstandard-analysis

I can across transfinite numbers and came up with a thought.

What if$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=f(T)$$where $T$ was a transfinite number?

Generally, in calculus, I have noted that it is two different things, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne f(a)$.  Which makes me wonder about the situation $a=\infty$.  Which means it must mean something when we compare $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $f(\infty)$.  The two being different, I guessed the above statement about limits to infinite and transfinite numbers.

Because by definition:$$R<T<\infty$$where $R$ is the real numbers.

By definition:$$\lim_{x\to\infty_1^-}x<\infty_1$$Where the subscript indicates the two infinities are equal.  In general, the limit from the left side is close, but always less than the actual value.  At least, that is my understanding.

But at the same time, a limit to infinite is a limit by which $x$ exceeds real numbers.

So in a sense, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=f(T)$.

My question is whether or not my "postulation" is correct.

I have also noted that sometimes, on very rare occasions, the following is true:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\ne f(\infty)$$

I will leave this up to you guys.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this is mathematics. I'm voting to close as such.

Comment: How is this not mathematics?  Where should I post this?  Thank you.

Comment: I guess the sentence "Because by definition $R < T < \infty$ where $R$ is the real numbers" is what got me. It just looks like a bunch of ideas were thrown together, and then it is "left up to [us]" to try make sense of it. I'll withdraw the close vote, but I think there's a lot to be wary of.

Comment: @pjs36 Thank you for your reconsideration.  I agree that this idea is a little slippery, but I just wanted to make it out there.

Comment: What is the domain of your $f$? Since you write $f(T)$, we must assume that the domain contains $T$ as a member. But can we not change the value of $f$ at $T$ in any way we like, without changing $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$? For example with $f: \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \aleph_0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=42$ for $x<\aleph_0$ and $f(\aleph_0)=43$, what would you conclude? Am I missing something?

Comment: What does "transfinite number" mean to you exactly?

Comment: @pjs36, those inequalities are consistent with the Cantor-like idea of $\infty$ denoting an "ultimate infinity" beyond all the individual ordinals, (and also with nonstandard analysis).  For the same reason the Conway field of surreal numbers, which realizes something like the OP's idea in characteristic 2, is a proper class and not a set.  So this is not in and of itself such an unusual idea or a dead end.  It fails in char 0, though.

Comment: @zyx Would like to mention that a) I have only learned part of calculus and am a high school student and b) that some of your words make sense, some don't, and c)I'm still learning set theory/number theory.

Comment: The short answer is that for purposes of having limits be $f(Z)$ for some "infinite" $Z$ the thing that is usually done is to extend the real line by two additional points, $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, and *define* $f(\infty)$ to mean $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ when that exists.   Other number systems that include infinite numbers ( things like "nonstandard analysis" and "surreal numbers") are drastically more complicated than that and not so relevant to calculus at the learning stage.   @SimpleArt

Comment: Thank you @zyx.  That does make some sense.

Comment: @SimpleArt, infinitesimals and infinite numbers are actually quite useful in learning calculus, as shown by controlled studies that have been published in both mathematical and education literature. See my answer for a concrete realisation of your fine proposal.

Comment: @user72694 Thank you for your opinion.  I will do that.

Comment: @user72694, the comments are a bit propagandistic. Infinitesimals in some form can be very useful for calculus, and were for centuries, but the very small number of "controlled studies" (if they really have the kind of statistical validity you imply) don't address the question of whether those infinitary things are best introduced using Robinson's approach or much easier earlier ideas, such as sequences and functions tending to $0$, adding $\pm \infty$ as a point to the real line, and other simple definitional and notational devices.

Comment: @zyx I'm sorry if you think that.  TBH, I don't get most of the comments... And I wonder about everything you said...I will think about your comments as well.

Comment: @SimpleArt, as background and context, the status and usefulness of nonstandard analysis is a sort of "debate" in mathematics that has been happening since the subject was invented.   User72694 is, I think, the currently most vocal public advocate (within the mathematics profession) for nonstandard analysis.  This advocacy has led to some nice postings on math.stackexchange, but also some promotional material some of which I just replied to (in its capacity as promotional material).   Not such a big deal either way, as anyone can study NSA and decide if it suits them or not.

Comment: @zyx XD .  Ok.  In general, I want to learn all of the maths, so meh, I'll learn it someday.  What's your favorite math sub-category/something?

Comment: See [tag:nonstandard-analysis].

Comment: @user72694 You know I'm only a High Schooler, right?  I'm still learning calculus. (T_T)  This is too much!

Comment: @SimpleArt, I was just responding to your question regarding what the corresponding category is at SE.  As far as sources of information, the best one is the textbook by Keisler https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html that I mentioned in my *answer*.  We are currently using it to teach infinitesimal calculus to 120 freshmen (we did last year, as well).

Comment: @user72694 Oh, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is a sound one and is the source of the definition of limit of a real function $f$ via the hyperreals.  Namely, to find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity, we evaluate $f$ at an infinite number, say $H$, obtaining $f(H)$.  This is not quite the limit since it is in general a hyperreal number rather than a real number, so what we do is to round off $f(H)$ to the nearest real number (called its *shadow* or *standard part*).

Note 1. For transfinite $T$ one cannot in general define what $f(T)$ is, whereas in a hyperreal framework the *extension principle* is true. This principle says that every real function admits a *natural extension* to the hypereals, so that evaluation at $H$ is always possible.  For details see the textbook *Elementary Calculus* by Keisler, available online here: https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html

Note 2. For some historical background and a qualitative discussion see my *answer* here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92925/how-to-treat-differentials-and-infinitesimals/224425#224425

Note 3. Leibniz envisioned many orders of infinitesimals: $dx$ but also $dx^2$, etc.  Similarly, Leibniz multiplied his infinitesimals by ordinary numbers, so that $2dx$ is also infinitesimal, etc.  By taking reciprocals we get an array of infinite numbers. Similarly, the procedures in the hyperreal extension $\mathbb{R}\subseteq{}^{\ast}\mathbb{R}$ involve an array of infinite numbers rather than a single such number $H$. Thus, the limit of $f(x)$ will exist if and only if the hyperreal numbers $f(H)$ for all infinite $H$ have the same shadow.

Comment: I would question the soundness of my idea, but thank you.  O.o  I will look into hyperreal numbers.  All of that sounds really cool too!

Comment: Hyperreals are another name for Abraham Robinson's "nonstandard analysis".  The complication with this approach is that $f(H)$ is ambiguous; you need to choose an $H$, but there is no preferred way of constructing one (and in some respects, not even one $H$ can be constructed).  This is similar to the matter of which transfinite $T$ would work for calculating limits as $f(T)$.  For the goal of calculating limits, everything turns out to be the same as adding $\pm \infty$ to the number system and defining $f(\pm \infty)$ as the value of the limit, but done in a far more complicated way.

Comment: @zyx, your comment about evaluating at a transfinite number is not entirely accurate. See the *Note* I added to my answer.

Comment: The comment was accurate, and is not addressed by the *Note*.  The extension principle that you mention means that if we could uniquely specify an $H$, then $f(H)$ would be unambiguous.  But of course we cannot uniquely determine an $H$, so that $f(H)$ is ambiguous.  The only thing that does not depend on the choice of $H$ is the standard part, also known as the limit, and the $f(+\infty)$ notation retains just that.  This seems a lot simpler and more canonical than introducing nonstandard analysis (at least for the narrow goal of computing and understanding limits).

Comment: @zyx, the value $f(H)$ is indeed *unambiguous*. I will elaborate in my *answer*.

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1/x$.  If $H_1 \neq H_2$ are distinct unbounded (informally, "infinite") hyperreals, $f(H_1) \neq f(H_2)$.  The value of $f(H)$ depends on $H$.  In addition, any method for unambiguous determination of $f(H)$ (fixed $H$ but arbitrary $f$) provides a linear extension of the limit functional to arbitrary functions, which requires some form of Axiom of Choice.  Thus, in the unlikely event of having a reasonable method of fixing a unique $H$, the effects of this on determining a value $f(H)$ for given $f$ would not be describable in any sense other than writing the symbols "$f(H)$".

Comment: @zyx, I am not sure what you are asking exactly. As I mentioned $H$ is definitely not unique, but the limit exists if and only if $f(H)$ always has the same shadow (equal to the limit). You seem to be interested in discussing foundational issues related to AC etc, and so am I, but this is a separate *question*. I encourage you to post it.

Comment: It is direct commentary on your answer, not a foundational question of AC etc.  The logical equivalence between constructing a single nonstandard infinite $H$ and strong forms of AC shows that it is impossible to give a precise meaning to the words "evaluate $f$ at an infinite number, say $H$, obtaining $f(H)$".   All we can do is determine the properties that are independent of $H$, which leads back to standard analysis.

Comment: @zyx, Skolem constructed a nonstandard model of arithmetic without using *any* form of AC whatsoever.  One can form the quotient field of Skolem's integers and do quite a bit of calculus with that, as shown in a paper by Avigad. As far as your claim that constructing a nonstandard $H$ is equivalent to strong forms of AC, this was discussed extensively in this thread: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57072/a-remark-of-connes/112483#112483  Feel free to contribute there or elsewhere. I do think your question is a foundational one in the end.

Comment: The logical equivalence is for nonstandard *analysis*, is very well known, has several one-line proofs, and is explained correctly at that page not only by a Fields medalist who is knowledgeable in nonstandard analysis, but by an expert logician who holds MathOverflow's highest reputation score, and several other MO users.  It is very very strange to present that page as some place where I should go to discuss a "claim".  It is not a "claim", nor is it mine. It is a standard mathematical fact.

Comment: @zyx, we appear to have different factual databases :-) Could you cite a specific article containing such a "fact"? The Fields medal is accorded on the basis of *mathematical* accomplishment and it in no way bestows any papal (or otherwise) *infallibility* in the matter of *interpretation*. For example, Alain Connes made numerous interpretive claims concerning Robinson's framework that are considered to have been refuted today, see for example Sam Sanders' article here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.07434 I would like again to encourage you to post your observation in the form of a *question*.

Comment: Connes' remarks are something that you introduced to the discussion, instead of directly answering my comments (for example, by exhibiting an $H$ and a procedure for getting $f(H)$, or clearly acknowledging that those are fictitious).   I mention the Fields medal only to state the obvious: if a world-class researcher *who happens to be relatively expert in the subject* (2 published papers) is saying exactly what I said, and experts in logic say the same, that is strong if not definitive evidence that those statements you dispute were correct all along.  Of course they are also well known.

Comment: @zyx, what statements exactly are you talking about and what is their relevance to this page on teaching calculus?

Comment: (continuing).  Sanders' article does not seem to refute anything Connes (or I) said.  His article is 50 pages long and uses proof-theoretic/reverse-mathematical systems I never heard of, so I cannot judge it in 5 minutes, but it looks to me like it boils down to a very close analogue of two well known facts.  First, as I wrote above, that if you consider statements independent of $H$, that is the same as standard analysis. Second, that proofs of All(x)Exists(y) statements are more uniform than pure existence statements and are mechanically (A-)translatable to "effective" or constructive form.

Comment: @zyx, I did not mean to say that Sanders' mathematics disproves Connes' claims.  Rather, Sanders himself says in the article that Connes' claims have been largely refuted (if I recall his precise wording correctly). I am still not sure what you are trying to say about teaching calculus here.

Comment: One relevance to teaching calculus is: what happens when a student asks for a concrete example of an infinitely large/small number, or of how your proposed limit procedure works in detail?   The options appear to be either to dismiss the question by saying "uh, let's just call it $H$", or to use the ultrafilter construction to write down $H$ as a sequence (Keisler's book does this), which is the same as the standard analysis shorthand of defining an infinitesimal to be a sequence tending to $0$, with a huge layer of added mystery and nonconstructiveness.

Comment: By the way, the OP's proposal to use transfinite ordinal $T$ does not suffer from this problem, because there are many ordinals for which a computable notation exists.  Take $T = \omega^2 + 3\omega + 7$, or any other ordinal formula.   The trouble is not with writing down the objects or computing with them, but just the previously discussed issue of there not being any nontrivial definition of $f(T)$.

Comment: @zyx, you are not really relating to my point that large fragments of calculus can be taught using infinitesimals without any nonconstructive input at all. Skolem's construction of infinite numbers is just that: construction. Higher level applications may use higher levels of abstraction but notice that Connes himself exploits ultrafilters galore in his work.

Comment: @zyx, but as soon as you leave the realm of polynomials such infinities (e.g., surreals) don't get you anywhere.

Comment: ...Concerning your comment about teaching calculus, in our experience teaching calculus with infinitesimals (to over 240 students by now), students seem to relate better to infinitesimals than to some of the more abstruse aspects of the real numbers which as you know similarly involve elements of idealisation.

Comment: If Connes' criticisms of NSA are correct (which they are), and Connes' ultrafilter-dependent Fields medal winning work is subject to similar criticisms, then yes, his later more constructive work may turn out to be a lot more valuable in hindsight.  I suspect, though, that because of the ability to write down a lot of concrete operator algebras, the situation with his earlier work is not that of a blanket nonconstructiveness as with NSA where constructing even a single example requires ultrafilter or the equivalent.

Comment: @zyx, again I think you are conflating two separate issues.  As far as teaching infinitesimal calculus is concerned, I maintain that this is for the most part not dependent on any nonconstructivities beyond what classical mathematics routinely depends upon. As far as more advanced applications, what Sanders shows in his text is that the nonconstructivities you report on *can be routinely and mechanically eliminated* and therefore the net benefit to clarity of exposition does not ultimately come at any additional price in constructivity.

Comment: ...as far as more advanced applications go, Terry Tao's example is a good illustration of the advantages.  If you wish to describe a nonmeasurable set in an Archimedean setting this involves quite a bit of tedious work.  Doing so in Robinson's framework merely amounts to writing down a short formula exploiting an infinite integer.

Comment: (re: Skolem.)   I thought Skolem's construction and any variations thereof are limited by the theorem "no computable nonstandard models of arithmetic".  The same problem of not being able to write down and compute.  And it is very far from usable in a classroom.  The supposed killer-app of NSA is reviving 18th century style infinitesimal calculus as something rigorous and usable and I don't see how Skolem's work could relate to that.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to what you would tell a hypothetical student who asks for an example of an infinitely large or small number in the class using Keisler's book (or whichever you use).

Comment: @zyx, I think you are again confusing mathematics and interpretation.  The multiplication is Skolem's system may be noncomputable, but the construction is perfectly explicit and Skolem certainly would not have envisioned anything that wasn't.  If you want to discard Skolem's system on the grounds of nonconstructivity you can certainly do so but you place yourself in a tiny minority in the community of professional mathematicians today.  Specifically, I am not sure it would be appropriate from the standpoint of such philosophical commitments to "warn" the OP as you did about my alleged "bias"

Comment: We both agree that transfinite ordinal infinities "get you nowhere".  But they illustrate the difference between a formalism of infinite numbers that support computation and description of the individual objects, and NSA which lacks those features.   The whole Skolem discussion is off-topic here, since it has no relation to the project of doing or teaching analysis at the level we are talking about, or the OP's question, or our discussion of your answer.

Comment: Meanwhile, what do you tell that calculus student?  Are the options I described essentially the only ones?

Comment: @zyx, to respond to your question about a hypothetical student, in Skolem's constructive construction of a proper extension of N satisfying PA, an infinite integer is given by a definable sequence tending to infinity, for example.  Taking the quotient field of this, we take the inverse of this number to get an infinitesimal. Dragging ultrafilters into this is a way of obfuscating the issue of the appeal of infinitesimals to calculus students.

Comment: Keisler's book uses ultrafilters, and you are teaching Keisler's book and recommending it to the OP.   Keisler also uses Robinson NSA with a transfer principle, not nonstandard arithmetic (which, as discussed, suffers from similar problems, but is not our subject of discussion).  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you would ever answer a student in your NSA-based calculus class by talking about definable sequences in first-order Peano Arithmetic.  What *would* you actually say to an actual student wanting a concrete example, and willing to probe your response with further questions?

Comment: "*Sanders himself says in the article that Connes' claims have been largely refuted*".  Sanders cites two of your anti-Connes polemics on the Arxiv as the sole source of his claim that Connes statements about NSA were "mostly refuted".  He appears to be wrong in that assessment, because your arguments in the papers were either pure sociology (Connes did equally nonconstructive work) or irrelevant (there is a "definable" model of NSA; this doesn't address his criticisms, which are essentially the same as my comments here).   If there were actual refutations that I missed, please let me know.

Comment: *[not ]appropriate from the standpoint of such philosophical commitments to "warn" the OP as you did about my alleged "bias"*.   Bias is your word, not mine.  By far the majority of mathematicians, of all philosophical persuasions, do not use nonstandard analysis, and are skeptical of it as a way to teach calculus.  Those who have looked into NSA and not been converted (e.g., Connes)  tend to base their skepticism on the same sort of reasons given here.  "How do I write down an example and calculate" is not an extremist philosophical debating position, it is the key reason NSA is not accepted.

Comment: @zyx, MSE has been warning us about extended "comment" discussions for a while now. You raised some interesting points above, and more than one. Why not raise them in a broader venue, such as an MO, so that "the majority of mathematicians, of all philosophical persuasions" can contribute?

Comment: If you trace through the comments, you will see that I am concentrating on this question and your answer, not interesting new points for other venues.  The basic mathematical and pedagogical claim in your answer is that there is a more fundamental process of "evaluating $f(H)$" from which a second process (standard part) recovers the limit.   The still unaddressed question about that, posed several times by now, is whether the $H$ and its evaluation $f(H)$ can be assigned objective and computable meanings (such as an NSA number system) that can be explained to people learning the theory.

Comment: (and if there are good explanations, do those boil down to $f(\pm \infty)$ or the standard theory of limits.  Independence of $H$ and all that.)

Comment: *"teaching infinitesimal calculus ... not dependent on any nonconstructivities beyond classical mathematics"*.  There is a huge difference between the two.  Teaching standard calculus with classical foundations is constructive everywhere in the classical sense of no serious AC, and also strictly constructive (in Bishop's sense) in practice for every use case that a student would ever see.  The nonconstructivities are far past the horizon.  In nonstandard calculus, deep nonconstructiveness is lurking in every single exercise, unless the question I raised has a good answer.

Comment: Hi @zyx, thanks for your comments and sorry about delays in answering (I was teaching).  You seem to be asking whether "evaluating $f(H)$ boils down to $f(\pm\infty)$ or the standard theory of limits, independence of $H$ and all that." That seems a legitimate question that can be posed at SE or MO to see what "the majority of mathematicians, of all philosophical persuasions" can contribute.

Comment: I'm asking a question that only a teacher of NSA-based calculus such as yourself could answer: what do you tell the hypothetical inquisitive student and does it follow one of the two options I named?   In this regard, Note 3 of your answer uses the word "procedures" to describe elements of the nonstandard extension.  That is a metaphor used to explain NSA to mathematicians who understand things like asymptotic expansions and O notation.  Do you use this language with students learning calculus, and how do you explain it further if they ask what is a "procedure"?

Comment: @zyx, I posted this at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793/does-evaluating-fh-boil-down-to-f%c2%b1%e2%88%9e-or-the-standard-theory-of-limits if you like we can continue there.

Answer (score 3):

Adding larger points at infinity does not lead to anything useful beyond the effect of adding $\pm \infty$ to the system.  There is no known additional behavior of functions for large and growing finite real $x$ (which is what we want to analyze) that is not captured by adding $\infty$ or $\pm \infty$ to the domain, yet can be captured with additional transfinite infinite points.

Because the ordinals are discrete, there would not be any meaningful extension of $f(x)$ to values beyond $\omega$ (or $\infty$, or whatever the notation would be for the smallest infinite point added to the reals).  You could extend $f$ to be constant and equal to $f(\omega)$, or equal to $0$, or define $f(\omega + n)$ to equal $f(n)$ for all positive integers $n$, but none of these extensions would be useful for analysis of $f(x)$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I like the other answer better.  It appears to be more focused on my question.  Thank you though, I love your answer too!

Comment: No worries, thanks.  The hyperreal approach was actually addressed in comments earlier, under its different (and more common) name, nonstandard analysis.  I left another comment explaining this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  See, I can't know these things, so I just ask you guys... <3

Answer (score 2):

Here is (at least) one problem with this conception.  In the case of something as simple as, say,

$$
L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2+1}{2x^2}
$$

we should be able to use the conception to determine that $L = 1/2$.  And yet, if we plug in any transfinite number for $x$, we find ourselves unable to perform the arithmetic in any useful way to obtain $L = 1/2$.  Any transfinite quantity $T$ we plug in yields the indeterminate form

$$
L = \frac{T}{T}
$$

It doesn't matter so much whether it's "correct" in some Platonic sense as much as whether we can get any use out of it.  Without more of a framework behind your conception, it sure seems at first flush that the answer is no, we can't.

Comment: Why should $L=2$?  Shouldn't you get the solution $L=\frac12$?  And thank you on your input.  I'm not really sure about whether or not my idea was correct.  It was just a thought.

Comment: Oops, yes, I should have $L = 1/2$.  I changed my example halfway through and didn't make all the changes.  I'll go do that now.

Comment: @zyx, is there a theory of Conway's surreals in nonzero characteristic?  Do you have  a reference?

Comment: Well, there is both characteristic 0 and 2 in Conway's theory, surreals and nimbers.  You are right that characteristic is not the issue, and I will repost the comment in a different form.  @user72694

Comment: I don't the line of thinking in the answer invalidates the idea of the question. It leads to Robinson-like infinite numbers, for which $f(T)$ would be defined, but there would arise issues of which of the possible infinite values of $T$ gives the answer. The OP is asking, I think, whether pushing (ordinal) $T$ further and further to the transfinite one can somehow go to the ultimate limit directly. This runs into the difficulty that there is no maximum ordinal, and also the problems of how to extend $f$ discussed in other answers.  [This is a reposted edit of  an earlier comment.]

Comment: @zyx, there is a point of fundamental importance here that I addressed in my *answer* above: they *all* give the right value after taking the shadow.

Comment: Interesting! I stand corrected.