# Is arithmetic with infinite numbers fictitious?

Tags: calculus, logic, soft-question, infinity, nonstandard-analysis

In 1933 Skolem constructed models for arithmetic containing infinite numbers. In a 1977 article Stillwell emphasized the constructive nature of Skolem's approach; see [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=465766). Is this at odds with Tennenbaum's theorem on nonrecursivity?

This question is related to a *comment* exchange at [Does evaluating hyperreal $f(H)$ boil down to $f(±∞)$ in the standard theory of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793) where terms like "fictitious" are being applied to nonstandard models, as well as the following *comment*:

"*You wrote that hyperreals 'have precise definitions' (plural), which they do not. No matter how 'precise definition' is interpreted (definable, constructive, Borel, ZF+DC), there is no such way to name an individual H. The role of ZFC in your arguments is indistinguishable from a single axiom 'an H exists'. When we assume a Zeus exists, draw conclusions that apply to any element of the set of Zeuses, and the argument works equally well with Zeus replaced by any Greek male over 180cm tall, then Zeus is used only as a metaphor, (...).*"

Note. The point about a nonstandard model of arithmetic is that one can do a significant fragment of calculus just using the quotient field of such a model. Avigad did something similar in his article in 2005: Avigad, Jeremy. Weak theories of nonstandard arithmetic and analysis. Reverse mathematics 2001, 19–46, Lect. Notes Log., 21, Assoc. Symbol. Logic, La Jolla, CA, 2005. See [here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2185426).

Comment: Please provide a quotation where terms like fictitious or metaphor or Zeus are "applied to nonstandard models".   In the comment exchange, *your remarks* about how a procedure works in nonstandard analysis are described as having elements that are metaphorical.  I don't remember anything in these many conversations that described nonstandard models (vs references to individual elements of the models) as metaphorical or fictitious.

Comment: @zyx, who do you think you are kidding?  I am referring to your *fictitious*, *metaphor*, and *Zeus* comments in the exchange following this *answer*: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793/does-evaluating-hyperreal-fh-boil-down-to-f%c2%b1%e2%88%9e-in-the-standard-theory-of/1596341#1596341

Comment: I'm saying that you misrepresented and distorted the comments, which were not about nonstandard *models* but the description of $f(H)$ for individual *elements* of the models, the ambiguity of the expression $f(H)$, and other matters.  The issues around those don't really relate to the models per se.   The Zeus thing was about neither the models nor the elements, but an explanation of ways in which an argument can use its assumptions as metaphors and not genuine existence assertions.  I predict you will have a hard time finding material that matches the distortion you added to the question.

Comment: @zyx, the issue is the legitimacy of using Skolem's model even if it may not be recursive, and Robinson's framework even if it may strike Bishop as just as debasing as the rest of classical mathematics. The number $H$ cannot be viewed in isolation and attempting to do this is merely an obfuscation.

Comment: That is not a quotation that contains what you claim I said.  The stuff you just edited into the question doesn't contain it, either.  Maybe we need a thread addressing your distortion of Connes and Bishop.  The arxiv papers are pretty dishonest.

Comment: "*the issue is the legitimacy of using Skolem's model even if it may not be recursive*" .  Given that this all started from a discussion of Robinson's nonstandard analysis (e.g. in calculus teaching), and that nobody uses Skolem's construction for nonstandard analysis, this seems like a non-issue.   The recurring unaddressed question was what you would tell a student who asked for a example of an infinite $H$, plus details of the rest of the procedure you described such as how to compute $f(H)$ and take its standard part.  Is your answer "talk about Skolem arithmetic"?

Comment: "*legitimacy of Robinson's framework even if it may strike Bishop as just as debasing as the rest of classical mathematics.*"  You are the only one quoting Bishop here.  Other than some pedagogical objections to the complexity of the axioms in Keisler's book, his criticism was that the framework is formalism without meaningful semantics.  Not-meaningful can be taken in an absolute sense (as Bishop would have done) or particularized to the calculus context, as things that cannot be explained meaningfully to students.

Comment: "*The [infinite] number H cannot be viewed in isolation and attempting to do this is merely an obfuscation.*"  The description of how to compute quantities like df/dx in NSA always refers to the idea (what I am calling a *metaphor*) of an isolated individual H where (...$f(H)$, you know the rest...),  and would not pretend to be different from standard analysis if that were not the case.  Given the centrality of that concept for the most basic, celebrated, sales-pitch application of NSA and its very existence, the word "obfuscation" is out of place.  Nonstandard English, one might say.

Comment: zyx, some of your edits at MSE can cause puzzlement when you do not acknowledge ideological commitments that area at variance with accepted views of a majority of users here.  For example, your exchange with @AkivaWeinberger was a bit puzzling to the latter for this reason. Try to preface your answers and comments, whenever relevant, by the following disclaimer: "If you reject proofs by contradiction and the axiom of choice, namely placing yourself in Bishop's mathematics, then the following problem arises, etc."

Comment: That's a view you are projecting onto the discussion.  I am addressing mainly the lack of distinction between standard and nonstandard (in the stated context of your question).  I did not say anything about rejection of AC or proof by contradiction, and answered in the negative your incorrect speculation about the latter.  If anything, the difficulties with NSA may be less in constructive mathematics, given that theories of constructive NSA exist.  I am not familiar with them, knowing only the Robinson approach.

Comment: @zyx, you have touched on the crux of the matter in this last comment. Namely, what is the status of the standard/nonstandard distinction? Since Robinson's framework is part of classical mathematics as much as anything discussed in this venue (namely, Math SE), it seems to me that such a distinction is purely verbal. Therefore it should be avoided.

Comment: Compared to the standard alternative and to the motivating historical material, Robinson's framework falls far on the other side of objective dividing lines within that big umbrella of classical mathematics.  Unremovable use of uncountable AC, undefinability of the individual nonstandard objects, noncomputability of the model.  The complete inability to explain to students what is a concrete example of a nonstandard $H$ and how, exactly, to determine $f(H)$ and its standard part.  Those differences are not empty word games.

Comment: @zyx, your claims have no basis.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602977

Comment: As you astutely noticed, Skolem's construction (via sequences) of a number system including infinities preceded Robinson's by more than a quarter century, and Robinson explicitly states in his book that he was inspired by it.

Comment: "*your claims have no basis.*"  The comment thus dismissed contains 4 claims, 3 of which are close paraphrases of well known theorems.  For the fourth one, since you tell students that taking standard part of bounded $f(H)$ is an operation on its own independent of the function $f$, and not a fanciful name for the standard $f(\infty)$ limit-when-it-exists, a refutation would seem to require explanations such as how to compute $(-1)^H$ for given infinite integers $H$, like $(1,2,3,...)$ in the ultrapower model.  Let us know if you can do that, and exactly which claims you dispute. @user72694

Comment: @zyx, by the transfer principle, every hyperinteger is either even or odd. If it is even, then $(-1)^H=1$, etc.

Comment: Nobody doubts that. The problem @zyx raises is [for this specific example] how one finds out whether a given hyperinteger is odd or even.

Comment: @DanielFischer, zyx's objections are of a philosophical nature stemming from his commitment to constructive mathematics and intuitionistic logic. In the context of classical logic,  I don't understand the content of your objection.  Just take the residue of $H$ modulo $2$ and see if you get $0$ or $1$. I am not trying to be clever; I just don't see the content of your question.

Comment: I think you are wrong about the origins of zyx's objections. But irrespective of that, _how_ do I take the residue of $H$ modulo $2$ if $H$ is the hyperinteger given by the sequence $a_n = n$, and I take the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with respect to an ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ of which I don't know whether $2\mathbb{N}\in \mathscr{U}$ or $(2\mathbb{N}+1) \in \mathscr{U}$? If you know which, it's of course trivial for that $H$, but one can then still easily find sequences determining an $H$ for which one doesn't know whether $H$ will be even or odd.

Comment: @DanielFischer, $H$ is not even *defined* before you have a $\mathcal U$.  The reason I think there is no issue here is because in Nelson's approach, we are talking about *natural* numbers here (not hypernaturals) which happen to test negative for the **st** predicate. The same problem exists therefore for natural numbers--unless you adopt a specific position with regard to set-theoretic foundations, namely excluding systems involving **st** from consideration. You may enjoy reading  a more detailed treatment of these issues in [this text](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425) due to appear in RAE

Comment: I'm a hard-nosed "choicist", I _have_ a free ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. I just don't know much about what sets belong to $\mathscr{U}$. So $H$ is defined, and I know it's either even or odd, but I don't know which. And yes, we can also define ordinary integers so that we don't know whether they're even or odd. It's just much harder than for hyperintegers.

Comment: @DanielFischer, for applications like the proof of the extreme value theorem and the definition of the definite integral, one uses a hyperfinite partition into $H$ subintervals and it is often immaterial whether $H$ is even or odd.  Other applications exploit properties of divisibility of $H$.  For example, $H!$ is divisible by every finite prime. This is useful in applications.

Comment: Notice that my *question* emphasized Skolem's construction in ZF.  Would you care to comment why we are focusing on ultrafilters here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't really see the connection with the linked question, but to address your question in the first paragraph: No, the two results are not at odds. Skolem's construction is not effective - see the Ramsey-style argument going from the end of page 149 to the middle of page 150. All of this is non-computable. (Note also that it's not unique, either: there are many different ways to follow this construction, which will produce non-isomorphic models.)

The sense in which it is *constructive* is that it can be used to produce a *definable* nonstandard model (actually, several definable nonstandard models) of arithmetic. However, definable is much broader than computable. (Also, I believe most logicians would disagree with calling this "constructive," and I note that Stillwell does not use that word in his article.)

---

A further edit: Perhaps surprisingly, there **are** definable hyperreals. This was proved by Shelah and Kanovei - see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311165 published in *Journal of Symbolic Logic*; see http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2039354

(Also notice that "hyperreals" and "nonstandard model of arithmetic" are *very* different things!)

Comment: Thanks.  I take it Skolem's procedure is a construction to the extent that it takes place in ZF (rather than ZFC)?

Comment: @user72694 It actually takes place in much less than ZFC - the theory called "$ACA_0^+$" should suffice, if I read it correctly, which is vastly weaker.

Comment: You mean to say that it takes place in much less than *ZF*?

Comment: @user72694 Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Noah, the point about a nonstandard model of arithmetic is that one can do a significant fragment of calculus just using the quotient field of such a model. Avigad did something similar in his article in 2005: Avigad, Jeremy Weak theories of nonstandard arithmetic and analysis.  Reverse mathematics 2001,  19–46, Lect. Notes Log., 21, Assoc. Symbol. Logic, La Jolla, CA, 2005. See http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2185426

Comment: @user72694 I'm aware - but if you want to do the more heavy-duty stuff (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis#Invariant_subspace_problem if I recall correctly), that's not really enough. And it's worth pointing out the distinction - that building a definable nonstandard model of arithmetic is easy, but a definable hyperreal field is very hard.

Comment: @user72694, I'm trying hard to see the relevance of Kanovei-Shelah to the discussions of NSA.  It seems to be a definition in ZFC, not ZF, the word "ultrafilter" is everywhere in the paper (recall this was exactly the point of contention that e.g. Connes brings up about NSA), and it does not provide a way to write down individual $H$'s or compute with them.  It's not clear if elements of the definable model are definable, and if they were, everything in the paper is on a different planet from what can be explained to learners and users of NSA, say in calculus classes.

Comment: Tennenbaum's phenomenon is relatively robust with respect to the system of arithmetic.  It applies to primitive recursive arithmetic, which is the main system in Avigad's paper.  Maybe for that reason there is no model theory in Avigad's paper, he works syntactically. @user72694

Comment: "*one can do a significant fragment of calculus just using the quotient field of such a model.*"  In logic papers, yes.  Is there any working version of this used to "do significant amounts" (or teach them) of infinitesimal calculus as an applicable math/science subject?  If not, it seems like a pointless distraction to raise it in conversations about nonstandard analysis.  To argue that deficits of Robinson's theory might be real, but some other system, that nobody ever implemented, in some theoretical sense is free from those deficits, is just changing the subject.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, the issue of definability is mostly a philosophical one and was introduced into the discussion by Connes. This was thoroughly analyzed at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57072/a-remark-of-connes/112483#112483  How difficult it is is debatable; essentially the idea is to use all the ultrafilters together (sort of the way you do in Stone-Cech compactification).  Keisler gives a presentation of the argument in about 3 pages. At any rate the point is that all this is necessary only if you take ZFC as the starting point, whereas Nelson's IST is more hospitable to infinitesimals...

Comment: ...The reason you need to work to put them back in is because they were eliminated when ZFC was developed in the first place, following the philosophy of Cantor that infinitesimals are selfcontradictory, which as you know has not been confirmed :-) @NoahSchweber

Comment: @user72694, in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188808 you wrote that Kanovei-Shelah model is definable in ZF.  They claim only ZFC definability in their paper, and ultrafilters permeate the argument.  On the other hand ZFC definability usually implies the same for ZF so potentially they are writing a ZFC argument that gives definability without choice.   Can you clarify in which theory their model is defined?  Also whether they get "pointwise" definability of individual elements in the model.

Comment: It seems quite clear that Kanovei/Shelah does *not* work over ZF, since it relies on the existence of nonprinciple ultrafilters. Moreover, it seems that  the individual hyperreals are not definable, although I'm not as certain about that.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, it's the other way around: the Kanovei-Shelah model *is* definable in ZF because it is defined by a specific first-order formula in set theory; but to prove that the model is a *proper* extension requires C. This could be compared to the construction of the Lebesgue measure which is usually taken to be $\sigma$-additive.  But while the Lebesgue measure is definable in ZF, its $\sigma$-additivity cannot be proved in ZF; see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146813

Comment: @user72694, in more detail, do you mean that there is a formula of the shape "exists a unique $x$ such that...", proved in ZF in the paper, for which ZF proves that $x$ is a model of some theory of real analysis; but for which $x$ is the standard model unless the (also ZF definable) set of all ultrafilters contains a nonprincipal element, so that the ultrapower constructions in the paper become nontrivial?   If so, is there a uniquely definable element $y$ of the model, so that $y$ is nonstandard in ZFC, and in which theory is it provable that $y$ uniquely exists?  I asked Kanovei to comment.

Comment: Whatever key properties the K-Shelah model has was explained in my brief note on this page below, a couple of days ago. The model does not necessarily have definable nonst elements. You can ask similar questions related to the model, slightly changing angle of interest, but you know it's not necessary that they are commonly inspirational

Answer (score 2):

The exact content of the cited K - Shelah result is that there is a concrete formula $A(x)$ in the set theoretic language such that ZFC (not ZF!) proves that 1st there is unique $x$ satisfying $A(x)$ and 2nd every $x$ satisfying $A(x)$ is a ctbly saturated elementary extension of the reals. In brief, **there is a definable ctbly saturated elementary extension of the reals, in ZFC**. By some reasons known to those working in nst models, this is not true wrt ZF.

Also, it is **not** asserted that the mentioned extension necessarily contains a **definable nonstandard real**.

The key tool of the proof is to assemble all really relevant ultrafilters in a sort of superfilter containing **all of them** in some sense, by means of a product of Fubini type.

Comment: ::choosing a nonstandard $H$ and calculating $f(H)$ and then taking standard part This is utterly meaningless. You cannot pretend to calculating $f(H)$ prior you `calculate' $H$ (whatever that means anyway).

Comment: The utterly meaningless thing seems to be the same as the description (say by @user72694 here at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582790, that started all the discussions ) of how to use NSA instead of the standard theory of limits at $+\infty$.  I called it a metaphor, rather than meaningless, to talk (in this context, limits/asymptotics) about standard part st( ) and $f(H)$ as functions that exist independent of each other. Other than word substitutions like choosing H --> calculating H, metaphor ---> meaningless, I don't see any disagreement (yet) between my remarks and this answer.

Comment: You know, `methafor' is a term suitable for poetics, belles lettres, fantasy or something like that, and people who are versed in those things understand it perpectly. But if you use it in a scientifically oriented piece (let alone specifically mathematical) people start thinking what the hell is meant by e.g. calculate $f(H)$? Like what is $\sin(H)$ or the standard part of it? And sans any specifying which way a generic inf. large number is chosen? Does it make any sense at all in view of the de nihilo nihil criteria?

Comment: (in continuation as it eclipsed the allowed size) Just to make my argument clearer, let me ask, what is $\sin(H)$ where $H$ is an arbitrarily large real. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Is the 1st part, unique x satisfying A(x), done in ZF or ZFC?  It would be surprising, and a very nice example, if one needs choice to define a unique object.   Also, what is the cardinality of the countably saturated extension?  The paper builds the extension in uncountably many iterations, and it was not obvious from looking at the paper if there is any increase of cardinality during that process.

Comment: The unique existence can be proved in ZF, but the desired property - only in ZFC. And yes the cardinality of the extension defined in the paper can be way bigger than the continuum.

Comment: "Arbitrarily large" is not a property of real numbers, in standard analysis.  It, and some equivalent phrases, are a form of syntactic abbreviation that in computer programming is called a *macro instruction* or *syntactic sugar* in the formal language.  When applied to proposition $P(H)$ this macro is an instruction to form the longer proposition "for all $c$, exists $H > c$ such that $P(H)$".  If $P(H)$ is "$\sin(H)$ exists" then you get the obvious unpacking of "$\sin(H)$ exists for arbitrarily large $H$".  Maybe boring, but it does not share the problems of the nonstandard $\sin(H)$.

Comment: It may speed up discussion to assume that all problems of choosing/defining/calculating $H$ and $f(H)$ are solved by working with sequences modulo some relation that we won't ask delicate questions about.   If $H = (1,2,3, \cdots)$ then $f(H) = (f(1),f(2), \cdots)$.  But what is this "standard part of $\sin(H)$" that we hear so much about, as having a separate and more general existence than limits, and allowing limits (when they exist) to be *deduced* from it as a special case?  Or $(-1)^H$ for integer infinite $H$.  These are metaphors that acquire meaning only in the standard cases.

Comment: Well, so this way or another you agree that in standard setting "sin(H) exists for arbitrarily large H". Why then the existence of sin(H) for inf. large H (in a suitable extension of R or under axioms of a suitable nonstandard theory) is such a painful problem to you?

Comment: Thanks, this is all very interesting information.  Is there an upper bound on the cardinality that has a short description in ZF(C)?  Maybe as $|2^X|$ so that $X$ quantifies the "number of bits" needed to describe a single element of the model?  Or an upper bound on $\alpha$ for which the construction can be done inside $V_\alpha$ (or number of iterations of powerset that are used)?  The purpose of these questions is to try to understand the complexity of the model by some measure relative to the non-definable models built with AC.

Comment: That is not the problem.  One can view the existence of $\sin(H)$ as problematic or not.  From the sequence point of view it is automatic (if you don't ask delicate questions, such as why it is not equal to some other strange function).  Or one can raise questions about whether the operations in standard definitions of $\sin(H)$ extend in some reasonable way to nonstandard $H$.  So maybe that issue can be avoided. The "painful problem" is whether the story of standard part existing as a function independent of $f(H)$ and independent of whether the limit of $f(H)$ exists, is only a metaphor.

Comment: It seems as though you accidentally created two accounts. If you would like to have the accounts merged, follow the instructions [in the help centre](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). If that doesn't work, you can use the [contact us](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request a manual merge by an employee.

Comment: Standartd part st(x) exists (in any suitable *R) for every limited hyperreal x. There is absolutely no problem here. Of course it is not asserted that st(x) can be @computed@ by any sort of Turing machine.

Comment: The theorem "st(x) exists" is certainly part of a self-consistent theory (equiconsistent with and conservative over standard analysis).  The metaphor/fiction discussion pertains to descriptions that take place outside the theory.  For example, imagine that in the old days, there was a self-consistent theory of possession by demons, and the practical remedies it prescribed might be in some cases the same as in  (a subtheory of) the modern theory of mental illness.  The modern words and constructs can still be in closer correspondence to the actual use of the theory than stories about demons.

Comment: p.s I added a question in comments under the posting from the 2nd account, about the K-S paper.  You will not see notifications of comments from the other account (without separate log-in) unless the accounts are merged as @DanielFischer suggests.   Thanks for joining the site and answering, the explanations of results in the paper are very valuable and hard to obtain otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> Is arithmetic with infinite numbers fictitious?

It depends on your definition of "arithmetic with infinite numbers" and "fictitious".  The meaning of *fictitious* that this question was written to oppose, was in reference to certain descriptions of how Robinson's nonstandard analysis is used for calculus.  Those descriptions don't have any obvious equivalent for Skolem arithmetic, because Skolem arithmetic is not used as a tool for doing or teaching calculus, or for any other application outside of mathematical logic and model theory.

> In 1933 Skolem constructed models for arithmetic containing infinite numbers. In a 1977 article Stillwell emphasized the constructive nature of Skolem's approach. [...]

The words like *constructed* and *construction* have no particular meaning here beyond "formal existence proof".  Stillwell did not use the word *constructive* whose precise interpretations do not apply to Skolem's proof.

> Is this at odds with Tennenbaum's theorem on nonrecursivity?

There are computable number systems that extend integer arithmetic with additional objects that can be interpreted as infinitely large, and operations extending the familiar ones to the larger system.  Polynomials with integer coefficients and computable ordinal notations are two examples.  Tennenbaum's theorem shows that Skolem arithmetic cannot be presented in that way, with discrete computable data and operations on them.

> This question is related to a *comment* exchange at [Does evaluating hyperreal $f(H)$ boil down to $f(±∞)$ in the standard theory of limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595793) where terms like "fictitious" are being applied to nonstandard models,

"Fictitious" was applied to *descriptions of what is done with* nonstandard analysis, not the models themselves.  The idea that nonstandard models constructed using the Axiom of Choice have a lesser form of existence than constructs that do not, is certainly an objection that arises in discussions of NSA, just not in the one that you linked to.

The metaphors and fictions relating to NSA occur not (as far as I was asserting) so much in the existence of the objects, but in the descriptions of how the theory is used, such as the idea that there is an ability to take the standard part of bounded $f(H)$ (going beyond the standard rubric of taking limits as $H \to \infty$ when they exist) when this ability never materializes except as the standard thing.

To the extent there is a problem on the existence front, it is that taking individual elements of the nonstandard models is more elusive than just constructing the models, so that the description of "choosing a nonstandard $H$ and calculating $f(H)$ and then taking standard part" can only mean a procedure that is independent of $H$, which is standard analysis dressed in very marginally different words.  It doesn't matter whether one considers the individual $H$ to really exist or not, there just is no way to do things like compute standard part of $\sin(H)$ or other functions that depend nontrivially on infinite $H$.

> Note 2. The point about a nonstandard model of arithmetic is that one can do a significant fragment of calculus just using the quotient field of such a model.

Only in logic papers.  This is not a real "use" of nonstandard arithmetic to do calculus as something taught to and utilized by nonlogicians.

Comment: Many words with little if any sense. Arithmetic with infinite numbers (if you mean NSA) is the field (or extended field) structure of any (such-and-such) non-Archimedean extension of R. As a part of mathematics it is not less fictitious than 2+2=4 or any other application of your favourite Turing machine.

Comment: Yes, I gave an example of "arithmetic with infinite numbers" in your generalized sense of the term, and it is universally assumed that NSA and nonstandard and nonArchimedean extensions of R are well defined theories in the same sense as any other theory in mathematics. There can be descriptions (or sales advertisements) of the use of a non-fictitious theory that are more or less fictitious, because (eg.) they do not accurately describe the way in which the theory is used.

Comment: ::nonstandard and nonArchimedean extensions of R are well defined theories::: They are not theories, not methaphors, not sales advertisements, but mathematical structures as legitimate in principle as the number 7. A theory (in logic) is a list of axioms which describe some category of structures. There is no such a property of a theory as being fictitious, let alone `more or less' such, the closest thing is a theory which has no models at all, which is inapplicable to NSA.

Comment: The objective fact is that there are formal theories of NSA (or non-Archimedean fields, etc), either as stand alone theories or a subtheory of something larger like set theory; informal versions of those theories used in human-authored papers; and proofs in books and papers on those subjects.  Attaching subjective terms like "legitimate mathematical structure" to this is completely optional but compatible with what I wrote.   The idea of fictitious description refers to the objectively available material such as online descriptions of NSA and whether it matches the published NSA corpus.

Comment: For example, it is said that NSA gives a way to obtain the derivative as a ratio of infinitesimal increments dy/dx , which then justifies algebraic manipulation of differentials.  A look at books like Keisler and how they handle separation of variables will show that this is *fictitious* advertising. The  justification is not through nonstandard infinitesimals, but by making the equation $dy = f'(x) dx$ a definition(!), and using some other limit (sorry, "standard part") to make sense of $f'(x)$.  The situation with st($f(H)$) is similar.

Comment: Internet is a social, not mathematical phenomenon, a sort of massmedia, you know, 2nd oldest and all that, so it can definitely contain `fictitious advertising' (taking your wording) of everything.

Comment: But for st(f(H)) it is the textbook description of the theory.  I think the dy/dx story is not limited to the internet.  Anyway, the dy/dx thing is given as concrete example of what *fictitious* can mean here, that it is not some belle-lettres word from the philosophy department but a simple and straightforward matter of descriptions not matching practice.

Comment: And what is your problem with  dy/dx  or st( dy/dx )? Both are perfectly well-defined in any suitable *R and the latter is equal to y' under certain conditions. What offends you that much?

Comment: *what is your problem ... what offends you that much?* ///  I did not have a "problem" or take offense at anything.   I am giving examples and definitions of how descriptions of (the use of) a theory can be metaphorical or fictitious either in absolute terms, such as the description of Leibniz dy/dx ratio being rescued by NSA, or relative to more accurate descriptions (such as st(f(H)) being a metaphor for standard calculations).   All those things that are correctly or fictitiously described are well-defined as syntactic objects, there is no claim that the theory is ill-defined or fictional.